# Wordpress blog post url

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I have a simple blog page that just lists blog posts on a page called 'news'

http://my-site.co.uk/news

I have a single.php page to display the actual post when it is clicked on 'news'

The single.php displays the post but the url is http://my-site.co.uk/the-post-title.

Is this normal or should it be http://my-site.co.uk/news/the-post-title

How cam I get it to be http://my-site.co.uk/news/the-post-title

Answer (score 0):

If you have no other blog, then in **Settings > Permalings**, under **Common Settings** select "Custom Structure" and enter:

```
/news/%postname%/
```